# Loading Workflow dll as workflowservice

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity, workflowservice

I have workflow service xamlx that has recieve reply activities

```
//Current Setup
string fullPath1 = @"C:\Projects\Learning\Workflows\Approval1.xamlx";
WorkflowService service1 = XamlServices.Load(fullPath1) as WorkflowService;
WorkflowServiceHost host1 = new WorkflowServiceHost(service1);

CompileWorkflow(service1);

host1.Open();


static void CompileWorkflow(WorkflowService workflowService)
{
TextExpressionCompilerSettings settings = new TextExpressionCompilerSettings
{
.........}}
```

// Would like to load dll instead of xamlx

```
string fullPath1 = @"C:\Projects\Learning\Workflows\bin\Approval1.dll"; // Not XAMLX
WorkflowService service1 = LoadWorkflowService(fullPath1);
WorkflowServiceHost host1 = new WorkflowServiceHost(service1);

host1.Open();
```

// Any ideas how to implement LoadWorkflowService()?

Comment: Load the dll into the appdomain, then use the Activator to CreateInstance of the compiled workflow.  Done.

Comment: This did not work for me, it errored saying invalid dll resource   //string file = @"C:\Projects\..\...\bin\TestWorkflows.dll";
            //Assembly a = Assembly.Load(file);
            
            //foreach(Type t in a.GetTypes())
            //{
            //    Console.WriteLine(t.Name);
            //    Console.WriteLine(t.Namespace);
            //    Console.WriteLine(t.GetMembers().ToString());

            //}

Comment: Well, the DLL is invalid.  The reason why is in the exception.  You need to debug it.